# how to get live mouse position while holding mousebutton

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

i want to track the position of mouse on hold here is the my code for mouse hold

```
let i = null
document.addEventListener('mousedown',e=>{
    i = setInterval(()=>{
        console.log('hold',e.clientX)
    },1/6000)
})
document.addEventListener('mouseup',e=>{
    clearInterval(i)
})
```

but it turns out the on mousedown event clientX is the position where it was clicked not live position of mouse... how do i get the live position of mouse on hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this?

```
let start = null
let end = null
let move = null
let isHold = false

document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    isHold = true
    start = e
})
document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isHold = false
    end = e
    console.log({start, end, move})
})
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (isHold) {
        move = e
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different events in your function, one that checks the mousedown, one that checks mousemove and last that checks mouseup.

When mousedown is fired change a truthy variable from false, set by default to false, then in your mousemove event see if that truthy statement is currently true, if so log/display the x and y position. If the mouseup is fired, set the truthy variable to false.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("screenBox");
const coords = document.getElementById("screenCoords");

function findScreenCoords(box, coords) {
  let isDown = false
  let xpos = 0
  let ypos = 0
  
  box.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    xpos = e.offsetX
    ypos = e.offsetY
    isDown = true
  })

  box.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if (isDown === true) {
      coords.innerHTML = `${xpos} ${ypos}`
      xpos = e.offsetX
      ypos = e.offsetY
    }
  })

  box.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (isDown === true) {
      coords.innerHTML = `${xpos} ${ypos}`
      xpos = 0
      ypos = 0
      isDown = false
    }
  })  
}

findScreenCoords(box, coords);
```

```html
<div id="screenBox" style="width:400px; height:200px; background-color:#ccc;">

</div>
<div id="screenCoords" style="font-size:36px;"></div>
```